# "Not found" error when creating Driver Packages in SCCM/MECM

Tags: sccm

I am trying to import drivers and when I get to the part where I have to create a driver package I get an error that says "Not found" when I specify a network path (UNC) where Configuration Manager stores drivers added to this package.

The share does exist and I have full control of the destination folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue but the folder was already empty.  I found that the way I have Config Manager set up, it's using the server's local SYSTEM account in the Share Permissions when I tested this on a local server share.  Having the computer's AD account in the Share Permissions wasn't good enough.  Not sure if this can work with a remote file share which already had the server's computer account added to the permissions.

I suspect it tests the existence of the path with the account used to install Config Manager.  I was able to edit a package after it was created to use the remote file share path as the source and it distributed fine and works.

Definitely a bit of a nitpicky issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, turns out it wants an empty directory in which to dump a copy of the drivers. I just created an empty subdirectory and it worked after that.